# html - IE when printing more number of pages then IE became unresponsive

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I print more number of pages from html in IE after first time printing that particular web page became unresponsive. I am printing this using the below code,

```
function printdData(content)
{
    var textPopupWindow = window.open('','popup','toolbar=no,menubar=no,width=1,height=1 left=-5000');
    textPopupWindow.document.open();
    textPopupWindow.document.write(getPrintData(content));
    textPopupWindow.document.close();
}

function getPrintData(printData)
{
    return "<html moznomarginboxes mozDisallowSelectionPrint>\n" +
    "<head>\n" +
    "<meta http-equiv=\"X-UA-Compatible\" content=\"IE=8\" />\n" +
    "<script>\n" +       
    "function step1() {\n" +
    "  setTimeout('step2()', 10);\n" +
    "}\n" +
    "function step2() {\n" +
    "  window.print();\n" +
    "  window.close();\n" +
    "}\n" +        
    "</script>\n" +    
    "<style type=\"text/css\" media=\"print\">\n" +
    "@page \n" +
    "{\n" +
        "size: auto;\n" +
        "margin-top: 0.25in;\n" +
        "margin-bottom: 0.25in;\n" +
    "}\n" +    
    "</style>\n" +
    "</head>\n" +
    "<body onLoad='step1()' style=\"font-size: 12px;\">\n" +
    printData +
    "</body>\n" +
    "</html>\n";
}
```

This is the code I used to print the html generated content from the web page.
The 'printData' contains the html content going to print. **This problem is in IE only** but it works fine in chrome and firefox.

#### IE Specs:

- Version: IE 9
- OS: Windows 7

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing more details, a full autopsy of the code you've given cannot be performed. Let us know more details about the browser like the following:

- IE Version
- Operating System ("Windows _" I presume)

In the meantime try disabling all add-ons. That is a common efficiency drain for IE since the advent of add-ons. In addition if that does not solve what you need, try this thread: [superuser forum post](https://superuser.com/questions/543546/webpages-open-painfully-slow-in-internet-explorer-on-windows-7)

Comment: I am using IE 9 and Windows 7